# How to save switch with userdefaults

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

I have a switch that, when set to "On", activates the DarkMode and when set to "Off", deactivates the DarkMode. My problem is that the switch appears as "Off" when leaving the app if it is set to "On". The code for my switch is below, unfortunately, I don't know what to write so that the app remembers the switch state, can you please help me?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outletSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var intelligenceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var defaultLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func darkAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if outletSwitch.isOn == true{
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            intelligenceLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            defaultLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            intelligenceLabel.text = "On"
        }else{
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            intelligenceLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            defaultLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            intelligenceLabel.text = "Off"
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the title, UserDefaults. Research how to use use it for storing settings between sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Set the user-defaults like this:

```
if outletSwitch.isOn == true{
   //set to true
   UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: “outletSwitch”)
}
else{
   //set to false
   UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: “outletSwitch”)
}
```

When you want to read the value back:

```
let status = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: “outletSwitch”)
```

Do null checks as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You want to save the value of `outletSwitch.isOn`. You can do that like this:

```
@IBAction func darkAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if outletSwitch.isOn == true{
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        intelligenceLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        defaultLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        intelligenceLabel.text = "On"
    }else{
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        intelligenceLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        defaultLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        intelligenceLabel.text = "Off"
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(outletSwitch.isOn, forKey: "darkAction")
}
```

To restore the state when the view loads you can do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    outletSwitch.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "darkAction")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You just have to save a value with a key to your UserDefaults.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standart
/// saves your current switch status to key "darkmode"
defaults.set(outletSwitch.isOn, forKey: "darkmode")

/// gets your saved value from UserDefaults for certain key
let state = defaults.bool(forKey: "dark mode")
```

You can also look at [this link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-userdefaults)

There are also Pods you can use for this like [SwiftKeychainWrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper)